# Weblogic Domain Creation Java Error

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

While creating cluster domain using `./config.sh` in web-logic 10.3 in `RedHat Linux 5.11` I'm getting the below error in command prompt:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1366)
at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1366)
at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1366)
at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1366)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1082)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:903)
at com.bea.plateng.wizard.GUIContext$8.run(GUIContext.java:480)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

But the domain creations completes. Any ideas?

Comment: does it take a long time to create the domain ?
Try after adding these 2 jvm properties in the config.sh script : 
`-Djava.awt.headless=true`

`-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you response Emmanuel, I will try it and let you know...